# Sorting on Associative Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell, exchange-server-2007

Here's a script I'm using to get current mailbox limits, quotas, StorageLimitStatus and TotalItemSize for Exchange 2007 mailboxes.

```
Get-MailboxDatabase |`
    Get-Mailbox |`
    Format-Table DisplayName,IssueWarningQuota,ProhibitSendQuota,`
        @{label="TotalItemSize";expression={(get-mailboxstatistics $_).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}},`
        @{label="StorageLimitStatus";expression={(Get-MailboxStatistics $_).StorageLimitStatus}} |`
    Sort-Object -Property ********
```

I'd like to sort on the values contained in the two associative arrays e.g. Sort first by StorageLimitStatus, then by TotalItemSize.

My limited understanding of Powershell prevents me from building the correct Sort-Object. Any ideas?

Comment: Format-* commands should almost always be the last command in a pipeline.  Or second to last when the last command is Out-* or a redirect to file.

Comment: Thank you Keith, I appreciate the advice and info. Hunter Eidson's reply below explains why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format-Table is going to cause you problems there.  It only returns strings, so Sort-Object isn't going to find what you're looking for.  Using Select-Object is a better choice (you can pipe through format-table at the end to get the table output):

```
Get-MailboxDatabase |`
    Get-Mailbox |`
    Select-Object DisplayName,IssueWarningQuota,ProhibitSendQuota,`
        @{label="TotalItemSize";expression={(get-mailboxstatistics $_).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}},`
        @{label="StorageLimitStatus";expression={(Get-MailboxStatistics $_).StorageLimitStatus}} |`
    Sort-Object -Property StorageLimitStatus,TotalItemSize | Format-Table
```

As to the sorting, just list the properties you want to sort by, as in the example above.

Comment: That worked perfectly, and makes perfect sense now (Sort object expects objects, not strings). Thank you so much, and TIL!

Answer (score 0):

Per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx: 
If you specify multiple properties, the objects are first sorted by the first property. If more than one object has the same value for the first property, those objects are sorted by the second property.

So you could use:

```
| Sort-Object -Property StorageLimitStatus,TotalItemSize
```

Comment: The answers above have helped fix the issue. Thanks, but that didn't work: 

out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData" is not valid or not in the correct 
sequence. This is likely caused by a user-specified "format-*" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.